# Render Image from REST API Call

Tags: rest, image, rendering

Here's the `var` from the `function`:

```
var aoTiles = "<div class='col-md-4 tile'><div class='tileImg' style='background: url(" + [value=this.Image_x0020_Thumbnail_.Url] + ") no-repeat 0 0;'><span class='openRotator'></span></div><div class='tileTitle'>" + this.Title + "</div><div class='tilePrice'>" + this.Product_x0020_Price.toFixed(2) + "</div></div>";
```

Instead of rendering the image, I get nothing.

If I do something simple like this:

```
var aoTiles = "<div class='col-md-4 tile'><div class='tileImg'>" + this.Image_x0020_Thumbnail_.Url + "</div><div class='tileTitle'>" + this.Title + "</div><div class='tilePrice'>" + this.Product_x0020_Price.toFixed(2) + "</div></div>";
```

If you need the full `function`:

```
function addOnsTiles(){
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "/_api/lists/getByTitle('Products')/items",
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose", "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {  
            $.each(data.d.results, function () {
                var aoTiles = "<div class='col-md-4 tile'><div class='tileImg'>" + this.Image_x0020_Thumbnail_.Url + "</div><div class='tileTitle'>" + this.Title + "</div><div class='tilePrice'>" + this.Product_x0020_Price.toFixed(2) + "</div></div>";
                $('.aoTilesTopWrapper').append(aoTiles);
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data.statusText);
        }
    });

return true;
}
```

It gives me the image URL but still no image.

Why is it not rendering?

Comment: Do you see anything in the console log for Chrome? A mime error perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is giving you the image URL, but not displaying the image, it is because you will need to add your image tag. Otherwise, the output will simply be your text, within the respective div.

```
var aoTiles = "<div class='col-md-4 tile'><div class='tileImg'><img src='" + this.Image_x0020_Thumbnail_.Url + "'></div><div class='tileTitle'>" + this.Title + "</div><div class='tilePrice'>" + this.Product_x0020_Price.toFixed(2) + "</div></div>";
```

as a background, you should be able to use the following:

```
var aoTiles = "<div class='col-md-4 tile'><div class='tileImg' style='background: url('" + this.Image_x0020_Thumbnail_.Url + "')'></div><div class='tileTitle'>" + this.Title + "</div><div class='tilePrice'>" + this.Product_x0020_Price.toFixed(2) + "</div></div>";
```

Please verify the syntax, but you should be able to `console.log(aoTiles)` and see what is within each loop, but use the console to see any script errors. You may also have a scenario, where you will need to define a width for tileImage in your CSS.

Comment: I was trying to bring in the image as an inline background style. Is that not possible?

Comment: I added the requested code, to display as a background.